# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] using Angular JS and highcharts-ng

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I am having a problem with implementing Highcharts in my Angular/Node/Express app. Using the highcharts-ng directive https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng

I keep getting the following error in my console:

> angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=stocksApp&p1=Error%…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A390)

I have this in the head of my index.html:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-route.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!--link custom CSS file -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>   
</head>
```

My template file:

```
<div class="container">

    <highchart id="chart1" config="chartConfig"></highchart>

</div>
```

My Angular JS config:

```
angular.module("stocksApp", ['ngRoute', 'highcharts-ng'])
   .config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
           templateUrl: "stocks.html",
           controller: "mainController",

        });
})
```

Can anyone help me what this error is about?

Comment: Seems you are not including the `highcharts-ng.js` in your `<script>` tags?

Comment: true ! and you'll probably need to include your lib before your `app.js`

Comment: Do i need to include highcharts-ng.js script tag? I installed with npm: npm install highcharts-ng

Comment: I also tried to put   <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>  before my app.js, but still the same problem...

Comment: Yes you need to, It will be inside your `node_modules` directory, you need include as `<script src="path_to_your_node_modules/folder_name/highcharts-ng.js"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that you have installed the `highcharts-ng.js` from the `Node` and it seems you have not included the same in your `<script>` block. You can find it under your `node_modules` directory.

Also as Steve Pitis pointed out, You need move your `<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>` before your `app.js` script inclusion.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks! My index.html is in the /public folder and I have included a script like this <script src="../node_modules/highcharts-ng/dist/highcharts-ng.js"></script>. However I get a 404 saying that https://myapp.com/app/node_modules/highcharts-ng/dist/highcharts-ng.js does not exists....

Comment: Do you maintain a `public` directory to serve your `css`, `js` files?

Comment: Yes i do! public folder with 2 subfolders css and js. Should i copy highcharts-ng.js there?

Comment: Okay.. In that case put your `highcharts-ng.‌​js` in your `js` folder of `public` and include it in your code the usual way you do.